# Is not a comma more than warranted in this kind of situation?

Tags: punctuation, commas, flow

From *The Two Towers*:

> To his simple mind ordinary hunger, the desire to eat hobbits, had seemed the chief danger in Gollum. He realized now that it was not so: Gollum was feeling the terrible call of the Ring.

This is not the first time I see this in English. It's equally jarring to me each and every time. If *I* had written that sentence, it would have doubtlessly been like this:

> To his simple mind, ordinary hunger, the desire to eat hobbits, had seemed...

To have "mind and ordinary" right next to each other like Tolkien (apparently) did (unless the digital copy I have has a mistake in it) seems extremely strange to me. Downright *wrong*! But since I've seen it so many times in English, I suspect that it is indeed valid. I just strongly dislike the practice.

In old texts, they frequently over-used commas, yet not in this case where it truly is warranted for clarity and ease of reading.

Comment: Hi Philant, can your rewrite your title? It's quite unclear to me what you mean with it.

Comment: The problem with the added comma is that it confuses the subsequent two commas, which legitimately separate a "parenthetical".  I'd say in this case the omission of a comma after "mind" is legitimately in the realm of "writer's choice" (especially when the writer is Tolkien).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a peeve - if Tolkien wrote something, ***by definition*** it should be considered "valid"

Answer (score 3):

There's often a trade-off between precisionist application of rules (admittedly probably calling for the comma here) and laying things on with a trowel, crudely overengineering (here, comma clutter). And the extra comma doesn't make things *all* that wonderful for the inexpert reader. How does one differentiate right away between the introductory-phrase parenthetical comma (omitted by Tolkien) and the two other parenthetical-offsetting (for the [whimsically narrowing/specifying] appositive) commas? We only have the one punctuation mark to serve different roles (or, as here, in an ambiguous [AB] + C **or** [A] + [BC] role). If we had a half-comma, that would work after the introductory phrase; the slight pause would show how I'd read the sentence.

A totally clarifying solution would be:

> To his simple mind, ordinary hunger – the desire to eat hobbits – had
> seemed the chief danger in Gollum. He realized now that it was not so:
> Gollum was feeling the terrible call of the Ring.

, – – and not the less clear , , ,

But this replaces the trowel with a larger one. The detailing apositive *is* best set off by the humble comma (one at each end).

I never had the privilege of meeting the good professor, though we may well have passed within yards of each other as we were brief contemporaries when I was at university. I *do* remember the story of his 'uncorrecting' an edit made to one of his submissions to his publishers. And I'm aware of his reputation as a linguist. In spite of which, I think his popular writing is unsurpassed. If he decided that a slight possibility of a garden path sentence was preferable to comma clutter, a different complication in parsing, and jerkier prose (or far more clunky dashes), I would be happy to agree (and do).

Let him who has better qualifications, a wider and more devoted readership, and more respect than Tolkien insert the first comma. (Is this a rant?)

Comment: I like the idea of a "half-comma". Back in the days of typewriters, that might amount to no more that striking the key a bit more lightly. Showing my age, I remember actually being ***taught*** not to hit the keys for "small" characters (full stop, comma,...) so hard as normal letters, because they'd come out too "bold" (not to mention making undesirable dents in the paper). I don't think many typewriters did things like "matched pair" quote marks either, but that's now trivial with digital text. (And I'm all for more of such "smart punctuation"! :)

Comment: ... But of course, would never stoop to using emojisϠ

Answer (score -1):

To my simple mind, your argument that we need a comma is correct, and the insertion makes the sentence clear. A quick internet search on "to my mind" brings up several authoritative examples, too tedious to repeat here, where the comma appears.

There is relevant discussion (but not an answer to your specific question) in [Using "to my mind"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81366/using-to-my-mind)

Comment: Well, some folk dislike the answer but have not said why. Perhaps Tolkien is beyond criticism?